# Static resources are not cached referenced from glassfish secure page

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, primefaces

I'm using JSF 1.2 and glassfish declarative security with j_security_check..

My xhtml page is in **secure_pages** folder and i secure all the resources in it by setting security constrant with web resources constraint as **"/secure_pages/*"**...

My javascripts and CSS are in another **(non-secure)** folder,which are referenced from the xhtml....

I've made resources cacheable according instruction given by link...

http://blogs.oracle.com/cwebster/entry/caching_static_resources_in_glassfish

Also in one of the discussion of stack overflow

[Enable cache of J2EE web application's resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371945/enable-cache-of-j2ee-web-applications-resources)

it written as,**it works, but not for security-enabled resources, where Glassfish sets the Expires header on its own.**

So my question is **"How can i set cache on this static resources?"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i got answer of my question after bit googling....

Just need to write the following property in sun-web.xml

```
  <property name="securePagesWithPragma" value="false" />
```

Comment: I've got a glassfish-web.xml, not a sun-web.xml and I don't see where this property would go.   Googling around suggests I need to add a context.xml file to the META-INF directory of my war file...

Comment: Actually above answer was given when I was using JSF 1.2 and Glassfish 2.x. But just post a new question for your situation with the Glassfish version.