# Resources first checked against server not retrieved from cache right away

Tags: jsf, primefaces, mojarra

Resources that are in ui:insert's,ui:include's are not cached. While the other stuff that is defined in my template is. The resources that are accessed in the ui:'s do have the right "Expires"-header, but they also have `Cache-Control:no-cache` & `Pragma:No-cache`. The other resources that are not accessed in the ui:insert and ui:include don't have this, like the stylesheets and js in the header. Now and then some random resources in the ui:'s do get from the cache, like 2 out of 12. And those 12 images are defined exactly the same way, I don't get why those 2 would get cached.

I have tried everything I can, and can't figure it out. (Mojarra 2.2.12 is used)

The param `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` has the value Production and the param `com.sun.faces.defaultResourceMaxAge` has 604800000.

Example of my main_pages_template, is use this template at various pages with the template-attribute in the ui:composition.

```
<html lang="#{localeBean.language}"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"      
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<f:view locale="#{localeBean.language}">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="default.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="cssLayout.css"/>
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="locales.js"/>
        <title><ui:insert name="title">Facelets Template</ui:insert></title>

        <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/favicon.xhtml" />

    </h:head>

    <h:body id="secure">

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="top">
                <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/header_template.xhtml" />
            </div>

            <div id="content" class="center_content">            
                <ui:insert name="content">Content</ui:insert>
            </div>

            <div id="footer">            
                <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/footer_template.xhtml" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

**Edit:**
Expample of the headers of an image that is not retrieved from the cache.

Response headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:6607
Content-Type:image/png
Date:Fri, 15 Jan 2016 15:55:26 GMT
ETag:W/"6607-1452873128742"
Expires:Sun, 14 Feb 2016 15:55:26 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 15 Jan 2016 15:52:08 GMT
Pragma:No-cache
Server:GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)
```

Request headers:

```
Accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=5ff7d3adafb1d4c47c82149f04c8; JSESSIONID=a56f8de3d3ad495ef464b309b91a; treeForm_tree-hi=treeForm:tree:resources:mailResources
Host:localhost:8080
If-Modified-Since:Fri, 15 Jan 2016 15:52:08 GMT
If-None-Match:W/"6607-1452873128742"
Referer:http://localhost:8080/webapp/secure/profile
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? Tried the latest to exclude a long fixed bug from being the cause? GlassFish 4.0 is pretty old.

Comment: The application is using JSF 2.2.

Comment: I explicitly asked which JSF impl/version. "JSF 2.2" is just a spec version. There are 2 main implementors, Mojarra and MyFaces, which in turn have various 2.2.x versions. Latest are 2.2.12 resp 2.2.9. Have you tried them?

Comment: I think it's Mojarra? I am note sure, based on this: "xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" I picked this project up at my internship never knowing that JSF is a spec...

Comment: You can find it in webapp startup log.

Comment: @BalusC Initializing Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) for context

Comment: Instead of using the ui:include for the header, I tried just putting the content from the header directly in the div with the id "top", it stil didden't cache those image. I also tried clearing the whole browser cache and see if it was something browser related, but no luck.

Comment: Now this is debugging and creating an [mcve], congrats, but it means your total question is kind of invalid, right?

Comment: 2.2.0 is ancient. Try latest, which is 2.2.12 as of now.

Comment: I did that and it now says: "Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12". But I still have the same caching problem.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/VCXe1ru.png - Here is a picture of the files, everytime it happends to the same files. Rest get cached those not.

Comment: which ones are not good? I see "200's" that actually come from the cache and 304's that (after a check on the server) come from the cache to... So you actually want to prevent the check to be done as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978189/how-304-not-modified-works

Comment: The btn_ images are a menu with a hover image change. So if a user would hover over the menu it would everytime check with the server if the image was modified. So I don't understand why it won't take the images from the cache as it does with the other resources.

Comment: @BalusC I get the same problem with GlassFish 4.1.1 and Mojarra 2.2.12

Comment: It's probally related to this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25342/headers-to-prevent-304-if-modified-since-head-requests ?

Comment: your question and especially the title, is now totally not in line with the answer. Can you try to make it more generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the server was responding with Cache-Control: no-cache and Pragma: no-cache because the resources were accessed on a secure page that was defined by a GlassFish Security Realm (j_security_check).

To solve this I implementend the solution here: [Static resources are not cached referenced from glassfish secure page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468099/static-resources-are-not-cached-referenced-from-glassfish-secure-page/5482987#5482987)

I added `<property name="securePagesWithPragma" value="false" />` as a property from `glassfish-web-app` in the glassfish-web.xml. Now only the Cache-Control header is set with the value, `private` which is fine. Private means that only the end user can cache it and not inbetween proxies.

Comment: This is not the default behavior. Something else in your webapp or even the server itself is setting those no-cache headers. So what you've done is merely a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: @BalusC Could it be that, because these resources are accesed from secure pages (security contstraint)? I am using GlassFish Security Realm (j_security_check). It would make sense because on the login page, that is publicly accessible, I do not seem to have caching problems. Could it be related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468099/static-resources-are-not-cached-referenced-from-glassfish-secure-page/5482987#5482987 ?

Comment: I think it does, but searching around the internet, I can't really find at what place in my glassfish-web.xml I should place it. When I get back at work tomorrow, I will just try to add `<property name="securePagesWithPragma" value="false" />` as a child for glassfish-web-app.

Comment: Oh that. I recall it. Awkward indeed. Surprising it still occurs on latest GF.

Comment: I think it does, as I also tried running my WebApp on the latest GlassFish with the Latest Mojarra, and I still had the caching issue. Here http://goo.gl/w23aqd is stated that indeed those two headers would be set to no-cache. The default value of it is true, so I think i've found the culprit?

Comment: Yep, GF is the culprit, not JSF.

Comment: @BalusC Updated my answer.